# How to split the a table in  database?

Tags: mysql, wpdb

Is there any option to `split` the `tables` in more `tables` in different `databases`? The problem is that my the `wp_posts` table is to big and it takes a lot of time to show in the Dashboards... (more than 20 seconds). I tried the `HyperDB` but this plugin just can split the database to different `databases` but the `tables` remain the same... Example: `wp_posts` from `database1` and `wp_postmeta` from `database2`, but I need to read and to write other ways...

Something like below

```
database1 --> wp_posts [from row 0--10000]

database2 --> wp_posts [from row 10001 to 20000]
```

etc...

I think that `searching` a single `post` between a lot of `databases` is not a big problem... there will be a great effect when `searching` through a hundred thousand of `posts` a specific query...
As my project idea is to make `WordPress` to handle a lot of `products` `(posts)`, so analyzing a single table `(wp_posts)` takes a lot of time, but splitting this `table` to more `tables` in different `databases` (a databases will have it's own server) will show a very impressive result.

Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

[Sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29) is probably not what you want, especially if the admin area is the only problem.  If things are working fine on the front end, you're probably okay.

How many posts are we talking about total?

Some things worth trying (please back up your DB first!):

**1. Remove all old post revisions**

A quick count of post revisions in my site reveals 5080 of them -- there are only a total of 700 posts.

Running a delete query like this should do it.  *Please test first!* Do not just run it on your production database.

```
DELETE FROM {yourprefix}_posts WHERE post_type = 'revision';
```

**2. Run an Optimize Table Command**

[`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) is meant to clean up tables that change frequently.  Since you just deleted what was probably a large number of rows, it can't hurt.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE {yourprefix}_posts;
```

**3. Stop WP from Saving So Many Post Revisions**

There is [a constant you can define](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions) in `wp-config.php` to do this.

You can disable them:

```
<?php
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);
```

Or limit them a max number.

```
<?php
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3);
```

**4. Remove Old/Spam Comments**

You could also try removing old spam comments from the comments table as well:

```
DELETE FROM {yourprefix}_comments WHERE comment_approved != '1';
```